# What be the default permissions of mysql directories in ubuntu

Tags: permissions, mysql, default

default  permission of

```
/etc/mysql
/etc/phpmyadmin
/var/lib/mysql
/var/lib/phpmyadmin
```

Answer (score 1):

/etc/mysql has 755 as octal permissions.

/var/lib/mysql has permissions set to 700.

Neither of the phpmyadmin directories are installed as standard, so I don't have that information I'm afraid, hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Arronical..  But the issue i am facing is when i am accessing tables using phpmyadmin some times i am able to open tables and alter them... and some time its giving 500 internal error so still tried with some permission change and forgot default.. But still 500 internal issue there same  if nay one help regarding that Thanks